# Reactivity on inner component's exported variable

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've been following the svelte tutorial online and got to this step (test it out): https://svelte.dev/tutorial/declaring-props

App.svelte

```html
<script>
  import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
  function click() {
    Nested.answer += 1 ;
  }
</script>

<Nested answer={42}/>

<button on:click={click()}>hi</button>
```

Nested.svelte

```html
<script>
  export let answer;
</script>

<p>The answer is {answer}</p>
```

Clicking the button doesn't update the text inside of the Nested component. Why not? How can I make a dependent (App.svelte) change the values in a component (Nested.svelte) reactively?

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code. Firstly you can't access variables declared in an imported component as properties. Secondly, you are calling `click()` in your handler assignment rather than passing the function reference. Last, you are passing a constant value `42` to the nested component, you need to either declare a variable in the parent to pass down, or bind to the variable in the nested component.

Comment: @pilchard how do you bind to the variable in the nested component?

Comment: see [bindings](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings) though it isn't really necessary given your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` in Svelte is not like exporting from a JavaScript module. `export let answer;` declares a prop called "answer". It does not truly allow importing "answer" and it does not exist as a property on the component object itself.

If you want to change the prop, you can declare a variable inside `App.svelte` to pass to `Nested`.

(In addition, you should pass the `click` function itself to `on:click` rather than directly calling it with `click()`.)

```
<script>
  import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
  let answer = 42;
  function click() {
    ++answer;
  }
</script>

<Nested {answer}/>

<button on:click={click}>hi</button>
```